# strContents considered as Junk value 'ÿ_[ when script executing

Tags: scripting, vbscript

I Have below simple script from heyscriptingguy.

The problem is the strContents is consider as Junk value 'ÿ_[

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/10/21/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-on-a-remote-computer.aspx

Junk value: 'ÿ_[

From scripting edit tool.i can see this value
[image]

Full Script is:

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
    ("\\USCOLB1\d$\LOG\log.txt", ForReading)
strContents = objTextFile.ReadAll
objTextFile.Close

Wscript.Echo strContents
```

What is wrong here? The same script works perfect in LAB

Answer (score 1):

The 'yunk' is probably the UTF-16 ByteOrderMark ([BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding)) and the file should be opened with the fourth (format/encoding) parameter of the .OpenTextFile method set to 1/TriStateTrue/Unicode ([Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx))